# Display pop up after 3 radio buttons are checked 'Yes'

Tags: javascript

I have a self-assessment quiz with 10 questions. After the user answers "Yes" 3 times, a modal is supposed to display with a referral link. I can't seem to get the code right, I've stored the radio buttons in an array and looped though the array, adding a counter variable every time the "Yes" button is clicked, but after 3 radios are checked "yes" the modal does not display:

```
const referralModal = document.getElementById('referralModal');
const radios = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10];
let count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
      radios[i].addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
        count++;
      });

      if (count === 3) {
        referralModal.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: What is `q1, q2, q3` etc.?

Comment: place the `if` code block after the statement `count++`.

Comment: q1, q2 etc. are the inputs/radio buttons labeled "yes",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this inside the event listener function

```js
const referralModal = document.getElementById('referralModal');
const radios = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10];
let count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (count === 3) {
      referralModal.style.display = 'block';
    }
    count++;
  });
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the modal now displays for anything greater than a count of 3, do I have to break the loop after the count gets to 3? I only want it to pop up once.

Comment: I've updated my answer for your problem, please check it now